# First Order Matrix System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following question:

Establish the existence of $N \times N$ matrices $S(x)$ and $C(x)$ such that

$S'(x)=Q(x)c(x),\\ C'(x)=-Q(x)S(x),\\ S(0)=0,$

where $Q(x)$ is a given continuous $N \times N$ matrix and $0$ and $I$ denote the zero and unit matrices. Now define

$y=CC^*+SS^*, Z=CS^*-SC^*$

where the asterisk denotes the adjoint matrix. Assuming $Q$ is symmetric, find a first order matrix system satisfied bt $Y$ and $Z$ and deduce that $Y(x)=I, Z(x)=0$. What does this result reduce when $N=1$?

Any help?

Comment: Do you know theorems on existence and uniqueness of solutions of systems of linear ODEs?  How to differentiate a matrix function?

Comment: Yes, I know. I need an outline or a main idea that I can follow to solve the question.

Comment: The existence of $C^1$ matrix functions $C(x)$ and $S(x)$ is guaranteed by existence theorems for linear systems of ODEs. Differentiating $Y(x)=C(x)C^*(x)+S(x)S^*(x)$ in $x$ we get $C'(x)C^*(x)+C(x)(C^*)'(x)+S'(x)S^*(x)+S(x)(S^*)'(x)$. Using the original ODEs we have that this is equal to $-Q(x)S(x)C^*(x)-C(x)S^*(x)Q^*(x)+Q(x)C(x)S(x)+S(x)C^*(x)Q^*(x)=-Q(x)S(x)C^*(x)-C(x)S^*(x)Q(x)+Q(x)C(x)S^*(x)+S(x)C^*(x)Q(x)$,  which can be written as $Y'(x)=-Z(x)Q(x)+Q(x)Z(x)$.  Can you continue?

Comment: Using IC: $Y'(0)=0 \Rightarrow ZQ=QZ \Rightarrow Z=Q^{-1}ZQ \Rightarrow Z$ is diagonal. Now: $Z \neq 0 \Rightarrow Y' \neq 0$ (contradiction). Hence, $Z=0$, am I right? How can we deduce that $Y=I$?

Comment: You cannot use $Q^{-1}$:  $Q$ is not assumed to be invertible. But we have already all the ingredients: the equation for $Z$ is $Z'(x)=-Q(x)Y(x)+Y(x)Q(x)$. The pair of constant matrix functions $Y(x)\equiv I$, $Z(x)\equiv0$, satisfies the equations and the initial conditions, so, by the theorem on (existence and) uniqueness for linear systems of ODEs, it is the unique solution of the initial value problem.